# Is every point of $f(z)=|z|^2$ a singular point?

Tags: analytic-functions, singularity

Consider the function $$f(z)=|z|^2=x^2+y^2$$ of a complex variable $z=x+iy$. The function is not analytic anywhere. What is the terminology here? Is every point a singular point?

Comment: A [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)) typically speaking is a point where the function is not defined. So $f$ has no singular points. $f'$, on the other hand, does.